# Clustering Kafka along with zookeeper

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I have 6 systems A,B,C,1,2,3. Kafka is installed in A(producer),B(producer),C(consumer) and they are configured. Now 1,2,3 have zookeeper installed in all and these three manage the kafka cluster. Is this the right way to cluster Kafka? Am i right about the logic used? If not please explain me the right way to do it. 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this talk by GumGum's principal engineer. He discusses how they use Kafka in their production environment. There are actually several of these talks on the web right now. My point is I don't think there's a simple solution to your question. You are going to have to decide what's right for your needs. In their particular setup, they only have one zookeeper server to manage their brokers, and use a load balancer to manage their producers.

http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/24877591